# homomorphisms between $Gl(n, \mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm tryng to find all differential homomorphism between  $Gl(n, \mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}$ (viwed as Lie groups). My first thought was find the homomorphis between their the Lie algebras, and then use the relation between the lie groups homomorphism and their Lie algebras. But I find two problems: 1) I don't know how are the homomorphism between $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}$, and 2) $Gl(n, \mathbb{R})$ is not connected.

So I think that I'm going to the wrong way. Any help wiil b welcome.

Thank You!

Comment: $GL_n(\mathbb{R})=\{A: \det A>0\}\cup \{A: \det A<0\}$ is the disconnection

Comment: one homomorphism would be $A\mapsto \det A$

Comment: @SenoreBunuel but, here I guess that I'm considering the group ($\mathbb{R},+$), so det is not a homomorphism because $det(A+B) \neq det(A)+det(B)$

Comment: It might be helpful to consider that the Lie algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ is trivial.

Comment: If you want them all, they are $A\mapsto \lambda\log|(\det A)|$ ($\lambda\in\mathbb R$). To prove it use the fact  morphisms have to be trivial on $SL_n$ (e.g. since $sl_n$ is simple), and also think what happens to the matrix $diag(-1,1,1,1,\dots,1)$ (with det=$-1$).

Comment: The trace gives a homomorphism if you're using addition as your operation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Basic_properties